# casting an int to an string in c problem in a function

Tags: c

I'm trying to get a number by using a getche() and then i have a functions that validates that number by getting the ascii code from it, at the same time if it gets validated it stores it in an char array, so i'm able to print it as a string, for some reason it is returning me junk. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>

validate(int number , int size)//validates the using ASCII table and prints a string
{
char cast[size];
cast[size] = '\0'; //ads \0 to the end of the array

if((number >= 48) && (number <=57))
{
    cast[size] = (char) number; //gets the number and casts it to a string
    printf("\n%s", cast); //shows the number
}

}

void main(){

int numbers;
int size;

printf("\nHow many Number you want to type? : ");
scanf("%i", &size);

for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
{
    printf("\nNumber : ");
    numbers = getche();
    validate(numbers, size);
}


}
```

[image]

Comment: Remembering that array indexes are zero-based, in an array of `*d` elements, what are the valid indexes? Is `*d` a valid index?

Comment: And please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). What are the numbers `49` and `50` supposed to mean?`Furthermore, naming a local variable `global` is a little misleading. And on that note, please try to avoid single-letter variable names, use descriptive names for your variables.

Comment: Also why do you pass pointers to the `funcao`? I don't see any need to use pointers here. And talking about `funcao`, what does it return? Never forget to add an explicit return type (even if it's `void` for nothing).

Comment: And lastly remember that you need to null-terminate your string after the last character, not the last element.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so i changed the code a bit and what i want to do is to cast the number of the function number if its == to the ascii code , and i want to print it as a string, check out the code bellow

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i edited the topic check it out, i made it more clear